# Dash lights flickering and engine cuts out

Tags: lights, dash

I have a 95 VS Calais, the last couple of months, the dash lights have started to flicker and some times the engine will cut out..
I have replaced the battery and the alternator with brand new ones..
And the problem is still continuing..

Anyone else having or have had this issue, or any ideas on what the problem may be?

(I have a video of what it does but I'm not too sure if or how I can attach it to this)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: So you have an electrical fault somewhere - and from the behaviour I'd reckon it will be an intermittent short circuit in the wiring loom. You'll need to check everything with a multimeter

Comment: I've done this and still playing up